# Java Script: Adding and Subtracting Variables Continuously Using onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to continuously add numbers by continuously clicking the button:

```
function burgersub(){
    if(document.getElementById("burg").value - 1 < 0)
    return;
    else
        document.getElementById("burg").value--;
}
function burgeradd(){
    document.getElementById("burg").value++;
}
```

Now Here is my Html code for button and form:

```
<p><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="burgeradd()">+</button><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="burgersub()">-</button></p>
<input readonly="yes" type="text" class="form-control" id="burg" placeholder="Amount">
```

Comment: javascript is not java ;-)

Comment: sorry my bad .. accidentally clicked java among suggested tags. thanks!

Comment: You'll probably want to explicitly convert the field's value from string to number and back to string.

Comment: how would i do that please?

Comment: Won't it be easier to just store your value as a variable and just rerender it every time it changes?

Comment: the actual idea is to create a program that adds quantity.. but everytime you click the add button the price of the product will be added.. it keeps adding until you reached decired product quantity and totals the price

Comment: this code working for me, what is your problem? you might have issue with other code lines

Comment: @JAVAC the my problem is.. besides making it increment just by 1.. i want it to keep adding a specific value for example 100  increment it by 100 every time you push button.

Comment: add an amount parameter to your method then?

Comment: @JoshHarrison how would you do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function burgersub(){
    if(document.getElementById("burg").value - 1 < 0)
    return;
    else
        document.getElementById("burg").value--;
}
function burgeradd(){
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value++;
    quantity++;
    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    alert(quantity);
    if (price) {
        document.getElementById("burg").value = price * quantity;
    }
}
</script>
p><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="burgeradd()">+</button><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="burgersub()">-</button></p>
<input readonly="yes"  class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
<input readonly="yes"  class="form-control" id="burg" placeholder="Amount">
<input class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Price">
```

Added 2 more textboxes to set price and see quantity and price

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (from the OP's comments) that you want to add a fixed amount on top of the number of items:

```
var burgers = 0;
var cost = 1;
var counter = document.getElementById("burg");

function burgersub(){
    burgers = Math.max(0, --burgers);
    counter.value = burgers * cost;
}

function burgeradd(){
    burgers += 1;
    counter.value = burgers * cost;   
}
```